Reviewer wants "post-hoc" power analysis for a mixed effect model
I have a multilevel model in a mixed design:
mod <- lmer(score ~ group*time + (1|id), data = df, REML = FALSE)

Where score is continuous variable, group is a two level factor and time is a three-level factor. id is the participants' id. There are in total 39 participants, and 117 observations.
I have significant interaction effects (two effects since the variables are factors: groupTreatment:timeOne_Month groupControl:timeTwo_Month , and I want to use simr to at least obtain the sensitivity power analysis (I am familiar with Dr. Lakens book), where he discusses what to do if editor asks for a power analysis in an insignificant effect.
I tried:
nsim = 1000
pow <- simr::powerCurve(fl_1_res, along = "id", 
             test = fixed("group:time"), nsim = nsim)
plot(pow)

But I got the "observed power", which is useless (the one I would get in SPSS MANOVA output). Am I correct?
The plot is: https://disk.yandex.com/i/3qbfTdGZ3O4t2w

When I try:
power <- powerSim(mod, test = "groupTreatment:timeOne_month")

I get an output with Power column with all NAs, and 1000 errors.
What am I doing wrong, and what is the proper way to a posteriory power analysis or to plot sensitivity power analysis.
EDIT: I ran fcompare(. ~ group*time) (mod0) on models with (mod1) and without interaction term (mod0), and I get the same result (p = 6.375137e-08) as with anova(mod1, mod0). All metrics indicate that the model with interactions is better indeed; but I am still not sure what conclusion I can draw regarding the power :/ Again, I am extremely grateful for you time!

Hi, can you post your outputs for "fl_1_res" and "mod"? Why did you use powerCurve to one model and powerSim to another? In any case, if you run power calculations on your actual model, you can only get post-hoc power.

@Sointu Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried different functions form simr and none of them work; although the toy examples work just fine.
https://disk.yandex.com/i/NfIUwUEe3x5qUw

Im sorry, mod and fl_1_res are the same models

Sorry, I got nothing - I quickly tried it with simulated data and it worked - your code seems to be correct. Simr is sometimes tricky with categorical predictors, though. Have you tried the fcompare test for comparing models with and without the interaction? That might be easier to implement and would give you the power calculations for the effect of the interaction.

Thank you so much for your time and effort! I ran fcomapre on models with (mod1) and without interaction term (mod0), and I get the same result when I run anova(mod1, mod0), with the result p = 6.375137e-08. I ran:
'anova(mod1, mod0)' and 'fcompare(. ~ group*time) (mod0)'. All metrics indicate that the model with interactions is better indeed; but I am still not sure what conclusion I can draw regarding the power :/ Again, I am extremely grateful for you time!

Please add new information as an edit to the post, not only as comments. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are often seen only by a few

@kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you for your guidance; I am new to this. The original post has been edited

On a rather non-statistical note, in general we are not obliged to do everything a reviewer wants. Editors, not reviewers, make decisions about acceptance of papers, so it is absolutely possible that an author gives good reasons to the editor why not to do something a reviewer has asked for, and the editor may just accept that. (Of course there is no guarantee, but I have published several papers without making all changes reviewers have asked for.) You could give a reference why PHPA are useless and see how it goes.

Sorry to leave you hanging. So, as we all know, post-hoc power analyses are useless.
However, if a reviewer demands one and you want to do it in order to get forward in the publication process, your attempts above are correct.
I'm not sure why you get NAs and errors from your second code. Your first (powerCurve) code seems to give you what you ask though (not entirely sure, hard to say without seeing the data). Because you feed your actual model and actual data into the powerCurve, what you get IS an "observed power" analysis. You can't get anything else. It is useless, but if you want to /need to please the reviewer, you can report this powerCurve result. It just shows in another way that your result was not significant, but if they want it they want it.
The fcompare you could use like this
powerSim(mod, test=fcompare(score ~ group+time))
#this will give (observed) power to detect difference between a model with and a model without the interaction; i.e., power to detect the interaction.

However, you could also try to run "as-if" a priori power calculations. For that, you need to forget your actual effect sizes from the study, simulate data, and feed the power simulation functions reasonable a priori values. Something like this:
library(simr)
set.seed(123)

#generate data that resembles your data:

id<-c(rep(1:40, each=3))
time<-c(rep(1:3, times=40))
group<-rep(g, each=60)
simdf<-data.frame(id, time, group)

#make time a factor

simdf$time<-factor(simdf$time)

#set random intercept and level 1 residual

rand<-0.43 #with sigma=1, this gets you an average sized random intercept variance based on psychology studies. You should refer to studies in your own field to find a suitable random intercept variance size.
res<-1

#set fixed effects: 

fixed<-c(3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1) #these you need to choose based on your knowledge about effects in similar studies, NOT based on what you got from your actual model. If you have no idea, choose small effect sizes. I just plugged in some numbers for the sake of the example.

#Run the toy model

modelsim<-makeLmer(score ~ group*time + (1|id), fixef=fixed, VarCorr=rand, sigma=res, data=simdf) #the function will create the dependent based on the parameters

summary(modelsim)

#Then you can run an "a priori" power analysis for the interactions:

powerSim(modelsim, test=fixed("groupB:time2", "z"))
powerSim(modelsim, test=fixed("groupB:time3", "z"))

If your study was in fact adequately powered to detect a reasonable-sized interaction(s), you can justify to the reviewer that your results are probably reliable.
